# Как сформировать массив из чисел, которые делятся на 3? С#

Tags: c#, массивы

Я попытался написать программу, но в ней есть какая-то ошибка. Как я понял, что-то не так с циклом, но я так и не разобрался в чем проблемс. По итогу программа должна вывести числа, делящиеся на три.

```
namespace ConsoleApp24
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int a = random.Next(3, 43);
            int[] mas = new int[a];
            Console.WriteLine($"Числа, делящиеся на 3:");
            int b = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < mas.Length; i++) 
            {
                b =+ 1;
                if(b % 3 < 0)
                {
                    mas[i] = b;
                    Console.WriteLine(mas[i]);
                }
                
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы просто запутались. Сильно запутались :) Но мысль верная была.

```cs
int b = 0;
for (int i = 0; b < mas.Length; i++) 
{
    if (i % 3 == 0)
    {
        mas[b] = i;
        Console.WriteLine(mas[b]);
        b++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- замените `b =+ 1` на `b += 1`
- вас не правильное условие в `if` должно быть таким

  ```
  if (b % 3 == 0)
  ```
- переместите `b += 1` внутрь `if`'а
- поменяйте `i` и `b` местами

  ```
  mas[b] = i;                 
  Console.WriteLine(mas[b]);
  ```

Comment: Это не всё, еще одну ошибку вы пропустили

Comment: @aepot какую?..

Comment: Условие завершения цикла